Rerun only failed jest tests using --onlyFailures flag on CI
When 3 of 10 jest tests fails for example.I am trying to re-run only the failed tests through CI using npx jest --testResultsProcessor="jest-junit" --testResultsProcessorOptions="{\"outputName\”:\”results/report.xml\"}" --onlyFailures
But it works only in local but not on CI . In CI i get no tests failed .I did try to get the path of previous test run report artifact and updated in yaml file
yaml file :
script:
- cd tests-${APP_NAME}
- npm i
# Rerun only failed tests with Jest options
- npm install -g jest
- cat tests-${APP_NAME}/results/*.xml
- npx jest --ci --testResultsProcessor="jest-junit" --testResultsProcessorOptions="{{"outputName":"tests-${APP_NAME}/results/report.xml}" --onlyFailures
But nothing works , i am not really understanding how this --onlyFailures flag works on CI .Please any thought do share it here .Thanks
I am getting aritifcats path and also printing the output of xml to see if the report is there in CI .But the command is not picking up the failed tests on CI .
